# Python gevent I don't see monkey patched the default file open/read/write/close, how to make file io in gevent async

Tags: python, gevent

In gevent monkey patch, I didn't see anything about default file object's operate.
How can I use async file read/write in gevent based programs?

Answer (score 4):

You could use gevent's fileobject.FileObjectThreadPool class available in 1.0b3:

```
pip install http://gevent.googlecode.com/files/gevent-1.0b3.tar.gz#egg=gevent
```

Then your example would become:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gevent
from gevent.fileobject import FileObjectThreadPool
import datetime


def hi():
    while True:
        print datetime.datetime.now(), "Hello"
        gevent.sleep( 1 )

def w():
    print "writing..."
    s = "*"*(1024*1024*1024)
    print 'about to open'
    f_raw = open( "./a.txt", "wb" )
    f = FileObjectThreadPool(f_raw, 'wb')
    f.write(s)
    f.close()
    print 'write done'

t1 = gevent.spawn(hi)
t2 = gevent.spawn(w)
ts = [t1,t2]
gevent.joinall( ts )
```

I see the following output with that code:

```
writing...
about to open
2012-08-13 13:00:27.876202 Hello
2012-08-13 13:00:28.881119 Hello
2012-08-13 13:00:29.959642 Hello
...
2012-08-13 13:00:58.010001 Hello
2012-08-13 13:00:59.010146 Hello    
2012-08-13 13:01:00.010248 Hello
write done
2012-08-13 13:01:01.469547 Hello
...
```

Comment: Apologies - depending on what os you are using this might not work for you. I just raised a bug about this not working on ubuntu 12.04: https://code.google.com/p/gevent/issues/detail?id=150. The gevent guys are pretty good at getting bugs fixed though so it might be working on all platforms soon.

Comment: FYI, Denis has now fixed issue 150 in HEAD of gevent, soon to be released as gevent-1.0b4. However, my original instructions to use FileObject were wrong - I've edited my answer to use FileObjectThreadPool.

Comment: Beware that Denis has recently [changed](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/commit/184bc92992dde92477be277a4860ecde4065ee4d) the name of `FileObjectThreadPool` to `FileObjectThread`

Answer (score 1):

Just did a test, says that write a large file will block the event loop

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gevent
import datetime


def hi():
    while True:
        print datetime.datetime.now(), "Hello"
        gevent.sleep( 1 )

def w():
    print "writing..."
    s = "*"*(1024*1024*1024)
    f = open( "e:/a.txt", "wb" )
    f.write(s)
    f.close()

t1 = gevent.spawn(hi)
t2 = gevent.spawn(w)
ts = [t1,t2]
gevent.joinall( ts )
```

the result is this:

```
e:\zPython\zTest>gevent.write.large.file.py
writing...  # wait a long time here
write done.
2012-07-16 09:53:23.784000 Hello
2012-07-16 09:53:24.786000 Hello
2012-07-16 09:53:25.788000 Hello
```

Comment: Isn't this part of the question —the "what-have-you-tried" bit—, instead of an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a threadpool (starting with gevent [1.0](http://code.google.com/p/gevent/downloads/list)):

```
>>> import gevent.threadpool
>>> pool = gevent.threadpool.ThreadPool(5)
>>> pool.apply(w)
```

Comment: yes, I can use threadpool. But my question is not focus on gevent usage. I want to found a way to do async file io in both windows and linux boxes. Of course with python language, and work together with gevent.